# Deploy Corda to Servers in AWS

Tags: java, corda

I am looking for a good documentation on how to deploy corda nodes on individual servers in AWS. I have a simple cordapp that I built locally for PartyA and PartyB along with the Notary. I want to be able to deploy this cordapp into a cluster of 3 servers. The documentation https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/deploying-a-node.html#linux-installing-and-running-corda-as-a-system-service is unclear about which jar to put where (asks to put the Corda jar under 4.5 which does not exist). Also, not sure what Network certificates are and do i have to use it. If so, how would I use it.

Following the instructions from above link and using root as the owner of all files (for simplicity), I get the following error:

```
Internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup: Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable. [errorCode=1917kd6, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.4/1917kd6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The guideline describes how to deploy a single Node into a pre-existing network in production. If the network is there, you need to ask the network operators for registration and they will provide you with the certificates.
Otherwise for non-production you can:

- join the [Corda Testnet](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/corda-testnet-intro.html), which is an open public network of Corda nodes on the internet
- create your own network with the Network Builder or Network Bootstrapper described [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/network-builder.html#corda-network-builder) .

The Corda jar 4.5 can be found [here](https://software.r3.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/corda/net/corda/corda/4.5).

Comment: I have taken a different approach. I have performed a gradlew.bat clean deployNodes on local machine and copied the node folder for each party to corresponding servers. and run java -jar corda.jar. I can connect to the server using Node Explorer but getting error when setting up path in Node Explorer > Settings. Is there any specific issue with this?

Comment: Are you connected to a Corda network? What errors do you get?